# "spark-submit" in DataProcCluster not running the jobs

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to run a java based spark application on the DataProcCluster,
Spark version that I use in my project: Spark 2.4.8
DataProcCluster Spark version Spark 2.4.8
When I run it I get the following error:

```
Application application_1676252836684_0013 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1676252836684_0013_000002 exited with exitCode: 13
Failing this attempt.Diagnostics: [2023-02-13 08:39:33.239]Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1676252836684_0013_02_000001
Exit code: 13
[2023-02-13 08:39:33.240]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 13. Error file: prelaunch.err.
Last 4096 bytes of prelaunch.err :
Last 4096 bytes of stderr :
onnected to master
23/02/13 08:39:32 ERROR org.apache.spark.SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Can only call getServletHandlers on a running MetricsSystem
at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:281)
at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem.getServletHandlers(MetricsSystem.scala:91)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:517)
at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
at main.GraphNetworkSCLAlgorithm.main(GraphNetworkSCLAlgorithm.java:355)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:686)
23/02/13 08:39:32 ERROR org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Can only call getServletHandlers on a running MetricsSystem
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Can only call getServletHandlers on a running MetricsSystem
at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:281)
at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem.getServletHandlers(MetricsSystem.scala:91)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:517)
at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
at main.GraphNetworkSCLAlgorithm.main(GraphNetworkSCLAlgorithm.java:355)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:686)
23/02/13 08:39:32 ERROR org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster: Uncaught exception:
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult:
at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:226)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.runDriver(ApplicationMaster.scala:470)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.runImpl(ApplicationMaster.scala:305)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.$anonfun$run$1(ApplicationMaster.scala:245)
at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$3.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:781)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1938)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.doAsUser(ApplicationMaster.scala:780)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:245)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:805)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.main(ApplicationMaster.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Can only call getServletHandlers on a running MetricsSystem
at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:281)
at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem.getServletHandlers(MetricsSystem.scala:91)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:517)
at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
at main.GraphNetworkSCLAlgorithm.main(GraphNetworkSCLAlgorithm.java:355)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:686)
[2023-02-13 08:39:33.240]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 13. Error file: prelaunch.err.
Last 4096 bytes of prelaunch.err :
Last 4096 bytes of stderr :
onnected to master
23/02/13 08:39:32 ERROR org.apache.spark.SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Can only call getServletHandlers on a running MetricsSystem
at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:281)
at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem.getServletHandlers(MetricsSystem.scala:91)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:517)
at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
at main.GraphNetworkSCLAlgorithm.main(GraphNetworkSCLAlgorithm.java:355)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:686)
23/02/13 08:39:32 ERROR org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Can only call getServletHandlers on a running MetricsSystem
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Can only call getServletHandlers on a running MetricsSystem
at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:281)
at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem.getServletHandlers(MetricsSystem.scala:91)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:517)
at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
at main.GraphNetworkSCLAlgorithm.main(GraphNetworkSCLAlgorithm.java:355)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:686)
23/02/13 08:39:32 ERROR org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster: Uncaught exception:
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult:
at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:226)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.runDriver(ApplicationMaster.scala:470)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.runImpl(ApplicationMaster.scala:305)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.$anonfun$run$1(ApplicationMaster.scala:245)
at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$3.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:781)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1938)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.doAsUser(ApplicationMaster.scala:780)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:245)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:805)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.main(ApplicationMaster.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Can only call getServletHandlers on a running MetricsSystem
at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:281)
at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem.getServletHandlers(MetricsSystem.scala:91)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:517)
at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
at main.GraphNetworkSCLAlgorithm.main(GraphNetworkSCLAlgorithm.java:355)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:686)
For more detailed output, check the application tracking page: http://spark-cluster-m:8188/applicationhistory/app/application_1676252836684_0013 Then click on links to logs of each attempt.
. Failing the application.
```

What is causing the error? How to solve this error?
I have added the MetricsSystem too explicitly. However, It is said that when initializing the spark automatically starts the MetricSystem. I am still clueless about what is wrong here!
My apache spark config is as follows:

```
                .set("spark.submit.deployMode", "cluster").set("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "6g")
                .set("spark.executor.memory", "6g").setMaster("spark://35.194.176.13:8188").set("spark.cores.max", "8")
                .set("spark.blockManager.port", "10025").set("spark.driver.blockManager.port", "10026")
                .set("spark.driver.port", "10027").set("spark.shuffle.service.enabled", "false")
                .set("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled", "false");
            JavaSparkContext jscontext = new JavaSparkContext(config);
        SecurityManager securityMgr = new SecurityManager(config, null, null);
        MetricsSystem metricsSystem = MetricsSystem.createMetricsSystem("GraphNetworkSCLAlgorithm", config,
                securityMgr);
        metricsSystem.start(true);
```